# Why is this the output of the code?

Tags: c

So, this is a output based question:

The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   char ch;
   if ((ch=printf( "")))
      printf("It matters\n");
   else
      printf("It doesnt matter\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Why the output is It doesnt matter? What exactly is being tested in the if statement?

Secondly, in switch case statements, if I do, something like,

```
char a[] = "abc";
```

and then I do,

```
switch(i)
{  
   case abc:
   ........
}
```

Why is this wrong? Cant we have string constants in case statements?

Comment: not clear enough: what is i? BTW, you should use "abc" instead of abc in the case statement

Comment: @vivoconunxino: *you should use "abc" instead of abc in the case statement*, to solve what, exactly?

Comment: So, we can have string constants in the case statements, right?

Comment: `char a = "abc"` that is 3 chars, not 1

Comment: @Tim Castelijns: `"abc"` is string literal that "holds" array of four characters: `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'` and _null character_.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski yes but should it not be `char[]` or `char*`

Comment: @Tim Castelijns: These are two different things, in `char[] a = "abc"` variable `a` is _string variable_, with `char *` you get pointer to _string literal_ (to first element of array).

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski I'm just trying to point out that `char a = "abc"` is not correct

Comment: @Jack sorry, I forgot you couldn't use switch on strings :P

Comment: @Tim Castelijns: In case of `char` it's about incompatibile types, `char` is not pointer type, in other words you are trying to put address of first character from string literal (i.e. `char *`) into `char` variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`printf()` returns the number of characters written. When called with a an empty format string (`""`), that value will of course be 0, which will be considered "false" by the `if`, and thus the `else` branch is taken.

And no, you certainly can't `switch()` on strings in C.

Comment: So, we can have only integer constants in case of switch case statements?

Comment: And in the switch statement itself, i.e. `switch(i)`, here,  i can be only an integer or anything else as well?

Comment: It must be an integer-valued expression.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski That's not in line with what the C99 draft says, and I don't think it's that much off. It just says "integer expression". You can do e.g. `switch (x+3)` for an `int x`.

Answer (score 0):

printf returns the number of characters printed, in your case 0 characters.

So you set ch to 0.

Assignment takes on the value assigned, in this case 0.

0 is false, hence the if statement goes to the else block.

Answer (score 0):

`printf` returns the length of string it prints on screen so `printf( "")` prints nothing so `length=0` so `if(0)` not executed therefore goes to `else` part.

`char a` is a character, not a string so `char a[]="abc" OR char *a="abc"` is valid and lastly only `char` and `int` allowed in `switch-cases` not `strings`

Answer (score 0):

- Look to printf function documentation

  int printf ( const char * format, ... );

> ... On success, the total number of characters written is returned. 
>   If a writing error occurs, the error indicator (ferror) is set and a
>   negative number is returned...